# Error en responsive de Tablero en Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, bootstrap, datatables

Buen día para todos,

Tengo un proyecto antiguo el cual, tiene como objetivo elaborar un Tablero con diferente información de una base de datos, antiguamente lo desplegaba el front-end de manera normal, pero estos días el responsive no esta respondiendo de buena manera, devolví cambios y seguía igual, hasta devolví a ese mismo proyecto pero un backup que tenía del 2020. He actualizado librerías de datatable pero sigue igual. Este el código de la librería de jquery que utilizo para ejecutar el datatable.

```
 $('#' + idTabla).addClass('table-hover');
            table = $('#' + idTabla).DataTable({
                'paging': true,
                'lengthChange': true,
                'lengthMenu': [[25, 50, 100, 200, -1], [25, 50, 100, 200, "Todos"]],
                'searching': true,
                'ordering': true,
                'autoWidth': true,
                'responsive': false,
                'fixedHeader': false,
                scrollY: "450px",
                scrollX: true,
                scrollCollapse: false,
                fixedColumns: {
                    leftColumns: 3
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    { width: 20, targets: 0 },
                    { width: 80, targets: 1 },
                    { width: 80, targets: 2 }
                ],
                "order": [[1, "asc"]],
                keys: false,
                language: {
                    "sProcessing": "Procesando...",
                    "sLengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros.",
                    "sZeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados.",
                    "sEmptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla.",
                    "sInfo": "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_ registros.",
                    "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros.",
                    "sInfoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros).",
                    "sInfoPostFix": "",
                    "sSearch": "Buscar:",
                    "sUrl": "",
                    "sInfoThousands": ",",
                    "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
                    "oPaginate": {
                        "sFirst": "Primero",
                        "sLast": "Último",
                        "sNext": "Siguiente",
                        "sPrevious": "Anterior"
                    },
                    "oAria": {
                        "sSortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente.",
                        "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente."
                    }
                }
            });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecía mucho que alguien me colabore con una solución.

Comment: Intentaste con `'responsive': true,`?

Comment: Sip, eso lo que me provoca, es salirme un icono verde pero no me cuadra la pantalla el responsive sigue estando mal.

Comment: Que versiones de Bootstrap y datatables estás usando?

Comment: Estoy utilizando Bootstrap v3.3.7 y Datatable v1.10.25